# Insertion of Date into Database

Tags: java, swing, jdbc

I have a `JDateChooser`.I need to insert a `date` in to a `Database` 
The input date is selected in the form of String.
I need to convert this `String` to a `Date` object.
What should I do.

```
    final JDateChooser dob=new JDateChooser();

    dob.setLocale(Locale.US);

    String dob_text=dob.getDate().toString();
```

Comment: Why is the input converted to a `String` in the first place? Both the date chooser and (most probably) the database know about date types. For what part do you want the conversion, the datechooser or the database?

Comment: Don't use Strings for dates. Use a `PreparedStatement` and the `setDate()` method (or `setTimestamp()` if you are dealing with date *and* time.

Comment: You should really have your date data in your database in date format, not String

Comment: Why you need to convert String to a Date if you already has a `Date` . `JDateChooser` returns a `Date`. Are you using `JCalendar` ?

Comment: "JDateChooser returns a Date".how to get that value?

Comment: `dob.getDate()` - just omit the `toString`.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
String string = "22-12-2013";
Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH).parse(string);
System.out.println(date); // Sun Dec 22 00:00:00 IST 2013
```

UPDATE :

Just got this from internet. You can get the formated date string from JDateChooser

```
Date dateFromDateChooser = dateChooser.getDate();
String dateString = String.format("%1$td-%1$tm-%1$tY", dateFromDateChooser);
```

This will return you in 22-12-2013 format. Then you can use the above code for creating a date object.

Another otion, you get a formatted string "22-12-2013". Now in mysql query you can send this string it will get inserted in database, you can also format the string date while inserting in database like below

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT('2007-10-04 22:23:00', '%H:%i:%s');
```

Comment: getting run time error java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Thu Dec 05 00:00:00 IST 2013"

Comment: What is the format of your date from JDateChooser ?

Comment: Dec 5, 2013 like this

Comment: Please check my post above, I have edited it.

Comment: still getting the error

Comment: can you post your whole code in your post. I mean actual post above. because its not giving error in my case